# WordML to PDF conversion

Tags: pdf, itext

We receive wordml documents which are basically XML files generated from msword docs which contains all formatting instructions also. Now we have a requirement to convert these files to PDF. I looked at iText xmlworker to do this conversion. What it did was simply removed all XML tags and gave me all the contents as single paragraph in PDF with no formatting.

How to make sure that generated PDF contains text with correct format from this wordml doc.

Comment: are you able to extract the text out of the wordml file?

Answer (score 0):

iText's product XMLWorker requires you to handle each XML element manually (unless you have HTML as input). The XML schema for MS Word documents is extremely complicated, so you'd be working on that for a few years to get something that looks even remotely ok. In short, XMLWorker doesn't do what you think it does.

If you want MS Word to PDF conversion, you need another kind of solution. XDocReport (MIT license) is one of these, and it has plugins for both iText 2 (LGPL license) and iText 5 (AGPL license). Results are not perfect though.